# Add Html code to Menu Title in Bartik

Tags: routes

I am trying to add my own image menu names (I prepared png files) instead of menu titles (Navigate, Category, Home etc.). How can I do this? Which files should I need to check? I know Html Menu module but it does not work on menu titles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd say menu titles should be text, for accessibility, maintainability and SEO reasons.

If you must, you could consider using CSS background images by checking the classes or IDs on those menu elements and adding CSS rules target them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MenuImage](https://www.drupal.org/project/menuimage) module. Hope you will got result as you want. I have not try this module.

> When editing a menu link, this module provides a file field to upload
>   an image to associate with a menu item. In the array returned by
>   menu_link_load, the fid of the image file is contained in
>   [options][content][image]. This may may be passed as a parameter to
>   file_load to obtain its public:// uri, and further used with either
>   file_build_uri or image_style_url to populate the src= attribute of an
>   .

**OR**

Use [Menu Icons](http://Menu%20Icons) module.

> This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's
>   configuration form.
>
> After uploading the image, the icon data will be added to the menu
>   link's options array.

Comment: [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) can be used as well with a background image set in css